# SHM with acceleration at mean position

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, terminology, harmonic-oscillator, oscillators

Suppose we have an equation of  motion as $$\frac{d^2x}{dt^2} = -kx + c,$$ then can it be called a SHM? Since acceleration is still proportional to displacement. But then, how will we define the mean position?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could rewrite your equation  as $\frac{d^2x}{dt^2} = -k \left (x + \frac c k\right )$

Setting $y = x + \frac c k$  gives  $\frac{d^2y}{dt^2} = -ky$

The equation of shm which can be solved for $x$ and hence $y$.

Comment: I see, so it's just like shifting of origin concept? As in, 'y' is the displacement from mean position, and 'x' is the absolute position. Is that right? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The mean position is $c/k$: this is just SHM about a point other than the origin, with the solution being:

$$
x(t) = a_1 \sin\left(\sqrt{k}t\right) + a_2 \cos\left(\sqrt{k} t\right) + c/k
$$